# Lightning record edit form picklist field

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When a lightning inputfield is used on a picklist field, if the recordId is provided dynamically (through onchange handler event for example), the inputfield isn't filled with the value of the record

Code :

```
{!v.sObjId}
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="someId" recordId="{!v.sObjId}" objectApiName="Object__c">
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="someId2" fieldName="language_Document__c"/> 
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="language_Documents__c"/>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Result :
[image: result of lightning inputfield]

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: I tried with your code and it was working for me, below is the snippet which I tried: 
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                              objectApiName="Contact"
                              recordId="0037F00000gWFc7QAG">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="level" fieldName="Level__c" />
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Level__c"/>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>

Comment: It's working when the id is provided statically. If I try to set it with an event, there seems to be a problem... I'll edit the question in a few moments

Comment: please add your complete component code